# I am trying to solve timus reverse root (1001) problem and facing the following problem

Tags: c++, arrays, root, reverse

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>

double buf[128 * 1024];
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    unsigned long long n; // 64-bit unsigned integer
    while (std::cin>>n) {
        buf[i ++] = double(sqrt(n)); // store in buffer
    }
    i--;
    while(i>=0){
        printf("%lf\n",buf[i]); // When i am using this it works fine.
        //std::cout<<buf[i]<<std::endl; // When i am using this line instead of printf function it shows wrong answer. why?
        i--;
}


    return 0;
}
```

I have compiled it with G++.
While I am trying to print the output with **printf** funtion then it is **accepted.** But when I am using **cout** function then it gives **wrong answer**. Why is it happened?
This code shows compilation error when i am compiling it in GCC7.1 . What is the reason of this?
Problem Link : https://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1001

Comment: Surprisingly, your question doesn't actually contain a question. Edit it to spell the problem  in title.

Comment: While I am trying to print the output with printf funtion then it is accepted. But when I am using cout function then it gives wrong answer. why is it happened?

Comment: Do you have an example input that fails the test? So we can see what the two outputs are, and work out how to make them the same.

Comment: I have written all the code above. In my pc compiler both are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `<<` operator with `std::cout` rounds to 6 *significant figures* by default and uses scientific notation for large floating point numbers. To disable the scientific notation, include the `<iomanip>` header and use `std::cout << std::fixed << buf[i];`. Using `std::fixed` will also set the rounding to 6 digits *after the decimal point*.

Comment: but why printf function is working without fixing the floating number?

Comment: @Sujan This behavior is specific to the C++ I/O streams. `printf` by default doesn't use scientific notation and rounds to 6 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @Sujan The rounding is done during the output operation, not during the calculations.

Comment: ok thanks. but the fact is not clear to me. Is there any tutorial on it?

Comment: Let me know if there is any details discussion on it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sujan Online tutorials for C++ generally aren't great, but a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539) might cover this stuff. There are detailed reference pages available online such as [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put) but the C++ rules are complicated and they are pretty hard to read for beginners.